# SwiftUI - Animating Multiple Parameters with Different Curves

Tags: swiftui

I'm exploring a sine wave rendering in a SwiftUI `View`, and have built my view to have 3 controllable parameters:

- `phase` (to control the offset and allow animating "horizontally")
- `amplitude` (to control how high each peak is)
- `frequency` (how many complete waves there are)

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

My `SineWave` is implemented as a `Shape`, so it is already `Animatable`. I made `amplitude` and `frequency` an `AnimatablePair` and expose it as my shape's `animatable` data like this:

```
var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
    get { .init(frequency, amplitude) }
    set {
        frequency = newValue.first
        amplitude = newValue.second
    }
}
```

This works, and I get a nice animation if I do this in my containing view:

```
    SineWaveShape(phase: phase, amplitude: amplitude, frequency: frequency)
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(Animation.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration: 0.1).repeatForever()) {
                amplitude = 0.1
                frequency = 4
            }
        }
```

Now I want to animate the `phase` as well. But I don't want this one to auto-reverse, and I want it to be much faster. Unfortunately adding another `withAnimation` block next to this one has no effect, even if I have it as part of my animatable data. The last animation block always wins.

How should I approach this problem of wanting to animate two properties with two different `Animation` instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible approach (sketch). Assuming you combine your animatable pair into struct, to work with them as single value, then you can use `.animation(_, value:)` to specify dedicated animation for each value:

```
@State private var pair: CGSize = .zero
@State private var phase: CGFloat = .zero

...

SineWaveShape(phase: phase, amplitude: amplitude, frequency: frequency)
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5).repeatForever(), value: phase)
    .animation(Animation.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration: 0.1).repeatForever(), value: pair)
    .onAppear {
        self.phase = 90
        self.pair = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 4)
    }
```

Comment: This looked promising but unfortunately I cannot get it to animate at all with this code. It seems the value parameter is just used as a trigger for _when_ to apply the animation, but doesn't necessarily use that value to interpolate the value used. My understanding could very well be flawed here, but in any case I can't get it to animate when using this method.

Comment: So it turns out that this approach is very useful if you have distinct animations for those values -- but on my case I wanted both to animate simultaneously. With this approach, the last animation overrides any current animations. I ended up changing my animation so that amplitude and frequency were animated together like this, and phase was manipulated with a timer separately.

Comment: Marking this answer as correct since it helped me get on the right path.