# SwiftUI: How do you animate from multiple values? iOS 15

Tags: swiftui

With iOS 15 you can no longer use .animation() without specifying the value you want to animate on. While this can be extremely useful you cannot animate on multiple values.

Example: If I want to animate the movement of two buttons, but the trigger is based on two values rather than just a simple bool. See code below.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
     if self.gvm.canPlot && self.gvm.points.count > 0 {
         Button {
           self.gvm.points = self.gvm.points.dropLast()
           self.gvm.hostFence = self.gvm.hostFence.dropLast()
         } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise")
               .font(.system(size: 19))
               .padding(12)
         }
      } else if !self.gvm.canPlot {
          Button {
             self.gvm.satelliteMap.toggle()
          } label: {
             Image(systemName: self.gvm.satelliteMap ? "map.fill" : "map")
                .font(.system(size: 19))
                .padding(12)
           }
      }
      Button {
        self.gvm.canPlot.toggle()
      } label: {
        Image(systemName: self.gvm.canPlot ? "arrow.up.and.down.and.arrow.left.and.right" : "mappin.and.ellipse")
          .font(.system(size: 19))
          .padding(12)
       }
}
.background(Color.theme.background)
.cornerRadius(10)
.shadow(color: Color.theme.background.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 3, y: 3)
.animation(.spring(), value: self.gvm.canPlot)
```

As you can see, .canPlot and .points.count > 0 are both used to trigger UI movement. However, .animation only allows for one value. Of course I could change other code to make this work. EX. Add a secondary .animation - or even not specify a value and live with the deprecation warning until it becomes an error.

Is there any simple way to use .animation based on multiple values? The older .animation would animate everything on the view, good and bad. Please let me know how .animation is intended to be used in this case.

EDIT:

Currently I have it working with this code:

```
.animation(.spring(), value: self.gvm.canPlot)
.animation(.spring(), value: self.gvm.points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```
.animation(.spring(), value: (self.gvm.canPlot && self.gvm.points.count > 0))
```

Comment: No, that would be like saying "Animate if canPlot is true and count > 0" Where as the "value" parameter doesn't animate when something is true. Rather it animates when  the value is changed at all. Good idea though

Comment: @Trevor Ah understood what you wanted to do from you edit. Looks like the way you are doing it IS the way to have multiple values in animation (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630729/swiftui-animating-multiple-parameters-with-different-curves)

Comment: Appears so, seems weird to me but I get what they are trying to do.